# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath call programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, methods, accessoryview

I have UIButton as accessoryView in UITableView. I implemented delegate method "editActionsForRowAtIndexPath". When I swipe everithing works nice, but I need this effect when I press the accessory button.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're looking for?  I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @fbara The question is quite clear. The question is asking how to show the extra button on the right side of the cell via code instead of by the user swiping.

Comment: @rmaddy the question wasn't clear to me, hence my request.  Feel free to answer the questions instead of advising me on what is clear to me and what is not.  Or, maybe, next time just comment with "Here's what the OP is asking about....", that would be much more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with MGSwipeTableCell class found on GitHub. It works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You may add custom accessory button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,20,20))
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourButtonImage"), forState: .Normal)
button.tag = indexPath.row
button.addTarget(self, action: "accessoryButtonFired:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
cell.accessoryView = button
```

Now perform the edit actions in the `selector` method

```
func accessoryButtonFired(sender: UIButton) {
    //to delete the row
    yourArray.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: yourSection)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Comment: The question isn't asking how to implement the extra buttons, the question is asking how to show the extra button via code instead of requiring the user to swipe the cell.

Comment: Edited the answer for `accessoryButton`

Comment: While this shows a way to add the accessoryView, the OP doesn't want that button to simply delete the row. The OP wants that button to simulate a swipe-to-the-left which will reveal the extra action buttons behind the cell.